# Laravel Session Facades and how to set which session to use

Tags: php, laravel, session

I use Laravel 5.7 for my REST API server, and I want to use mostly Laravel solution  whenever I can. What I need, on successful login I need to start session, return to front end in response, and on every new request I want to start that same session and read/write data from/into session.

I can do that with plain php:

```
$sid = md5('some_id');
session_id($sid);
session_start();
$_SESSION["name"] = "test";
```

And on next request when I use:

```
$sid = md5('mobile');
session_id($sid);
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

I got array

```
Array
(
    [name] => test
)
```

As I said I tried to use Laravel Session and can't figure out how to get same results. I tried something like this:

```
Session::setId('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');
Session::start();
Session::put('name', 'Yoda');
```

But I newer can't reach same session, always is new session.

Does anyone know how I can solve my problem?

P.S. In first solution also PHPSESSID is added to cookies, in second is not.

Thanks

Comment: Is this cross domain, for front end and back end?

Comment: Probably use [JSON Web tokens](https://jwt.io/)?

Comment: No, it's same domain. I use JWT, but I need this for another purpose. I found solution, in api middleware group I added \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class, and after Session::put I added Session::save.